How to make navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }) work on mobile browser, currently only wors on desktop browser. I am using https
i am using an OTG USB microphone with my mobile device, intending to capture audio input through the USB microphone instead of the built-in speakerphone. Despite the system recognizing the USB microphone as a media device, the audio input continues to default to the built-in speakerphone rather than the USB microphone when using the Firefox browser, Chrome and Samsung Internet. THis only happens on mobile browsers. I tried different cables aswell. I installed SSL on my localhost and its still not working for mobile browser
Tried it on android 9 and android 12, updated all browsers.
  async getMedia(constraints: MediaStreamConstraints) {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
      this.handleStream(stream);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error requesting media:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  private handleStream(stream: MediaStream) {
    if (this.audioStream) {
      this.audioStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }
    this.audioStream = stream;

    this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext)();

    const source = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const highPassFilter = this.audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
    highPassFilter.type = 'highpass';
    highPassFilter.frequency.setValueAtTime(20000, this.audioContext.currentTime);

    this.analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
    this.analyser.fftSize = 1024;

    const bufferLength = this.analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    this.dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    try {
      source.connect(highPassFilter);
      highPassFilter.connect(this.analyser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting audio nodes:', error);
      return;
    }

    this.draw();
  }

  async startMicrophone(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.stopMedia();
      let initialStream: MediaStream | null = null;
      try {
        initialStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
        initialStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      } catch (error) {
        this.updateNFCStatus('Error accessing microphone: ' + (error as Error).message);
        return;
      }

      const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
      const inputDevice = devices.find(
        device =>
          device.kind === 'audioinput' &&
          !device.label.includes('Speakerphone') &&
          device.label.includes('USB')
      );

      if (inputDevice) {
        const constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
          audio: { deviceId: { exact: inputDevice.deviceId } },
        };
        await this.getMedia(constraints);
      } else {
        await this.getMedia({ audio: true });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error selecting input device:');
    }
  }



Bug, maybe?  Mobile browsers' gUM is flakey.
