Chrome mobile browser and Samsung internet seem to be permanently set to phone speakers? Does recognize the microphone but does not switch to it?
When inputing otg cable it does not switch to the selected deviceId using getUserMedia on mobile browsers. It keeps using the default speakerphone on samsung galaxy note8 and note 10. I am using secure connections https and the browser version:
Desktop browser Chrome: Version 114.0.5735.198  (works)
Mobile browser Chrome: version 126.0.6478.188   (does not work)
I set up something that processes live surrounding audio (picked up by the microphone) and is replayed almost in real time from the phone's speakers.
However, this is producing feedback as the phone's microphone picks up the sounds that are just produced by the phone's speakers.
tried buying a new cable for connecting microphone, still does not switch. tried using headphones and the same thing happend. code : How to make navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }) work on mobile browser, currently only wors on desktop browser. I am using https

Welcome to SO. I think this is a SuperUser question and not a programming question - please do not abuse tags to generate interest. If it IS a programming question, please post code that shows the issue

@mplungjan it is both as the problem occurs with using web rtc getUserMedia by link    the code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78797554/how-to-make-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-audio-true-work-on-mobile

So why this question? I do not see why this one is a programming question - sounds like pure hardware.
